# How to call image,text and numbers that is stored in my database(without the images link)

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, mysqli

my problem is that i cant seem to call any kind of information that is stored in my database. I want to call everything in the order that it is in the database(name of the product, image and price. Here is the code for my index.php
Here you can view how my webpage looks so far:

[image: screen 1]

Here you can view the data that is in my database:
 [image: screen 2]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add to Cart</title>
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "id3764036_alan", "agro12345", "id3764036_agrotienda");


?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed|Rubik" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
a{text-decoration:none; color:inherit}
#undr{width:100%; height:580px; position:absolute; top:75px; left:0px;}
.bdimg{width:100%; height:100%}
#lowrbdy{ position:absolute; top:90px; left:0px;width:100%; height:100px}
.outer{width:270px; height:270px; background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8); float:left; margin-left:55px; margin-bottom:10px}
.imgdv{width:100px;height:140px;margin:10px auto;}
.imgdv img{width:100%; height:100%}
.pname{ text-align:center; width:100%; height:20px; font-size:15px; margin-top:-14px; margin-bottom:10px}
.prs{ text-align:center; font-size:24px; margin:0px}
.butndv{width:140px; height:40px; margin:auto; margin-top:-10px}
.butn{width:100%; height:100%; background:rgba(78,172,240,1.00); border:none; color:#fff; font-size:18px; border-radius:6px}
.outer:hover{ background:#fff}
.outer:hover .butn{ background:#4A7FDC; transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out; cursor:pointer}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <header>
  <?php
   include('head.php');
  ?>
 </header>
  
    <div id="undr">
  <img class="bdimg" src="bg.jpg">
 </div>
    
    <div id="lowrbdy">
<?php
$select_query="";
$sql  = mysqli_query($mysqli,'SELECT * FROM `product`');


while ($row = $sql->fetch_row())


{
    

?>              
     <a href="view.php?product=<?=$row["id"]?>">
         <div class="outer">
             <div class="imgdv"><img src="carrillo/imeg/<?=$row["pro_image"]?>"/></div>
                
                
   </div>
  </a>
<?php

}
?>
     
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your storing a file name in the db not an image.. check the path `carrillo/imeg/` actually has the image files

Comment: The images are stored here https://agro-tienda.000webhostapp.com/carrillo/imeg/ . what I want is that if I add new Info in my DB, it automatically generates anew image in my web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `fetch_row()` to `fetch_assoc()`. If you use fetch_row(), the $row variable will contain array with numerical indexes. With fetch_assoc(), the $row variable will store an associative array with column names as the indexes.

Answer (score -1):

Try Using prepared statement

```
<?php
$select_query="";
// $sql  = mysqli_query($mysqli,'SELECT * FROM `product`');
$sql="SELECT id, pro_image,name,price FROM product";
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
       $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $pro_image, $name);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        ?>
        <a href="view.php?product=<?php echo $id;?>">
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="imgdv"><img src="carrillo/imeg/<?php echo $p_image;?>"/></div>
            </div>
        </a>

<?php
}
}?>
```

You can also try with MySQLi Procedural
You have to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instated of `fetch_row`

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM `products`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>              
        <a href="view.php?product=<?php echo $row["id"];?>">
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="imgdv"><img src="carrillo/imeg/<?php echo $row["pro_image"];?>"/></div>
            </div>
        </a>
<?php
}
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```